# Reverted edit results in negative reputation?

Tags: discussion, bug, editing, reputation

Just a question ... some minutes ago my reputation was at "1665". An edit i made during the day was reverted by the questioneer, but insead of `+2` and `-2` I only see `-2 reverted` ... and reputation is at "1661" (instead of "1663")

Is this intented behavoir?

Comment: can you add the link to the question or the item in the review queue?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/177678/load-left-nav-in-ajax-request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see the + and the - items in your rep page. See the top and bottom entries.
[image].

But it seems to me that there is something wrong with your rep calculation.
I ran this very ugly but effective js script in the console while viewing your reputation page:

```
var total = 0;var elements = jQuery('.rep-cell .rep-up');for (var i = 0 ; i<elements.length;i++) {total += parseInt(jQuery(elements[i]).html())}
```

The total on the first page adds up to 1609.
The total on the second page adds up to 60.

and running it for the days where you have negative rep days

```
var total = 0;var elements = jQuery('.rep-cell .rep-down');for (var i = 0 ; i<elements.length;i++) {total += parseInt(jQuery(elements[i]).html())}
```

it results into -6.
Adding all this up you end up with 1663, as you expect. but you clearly have 1661.
I advice you to post this question on http://meta.stackexchange.com since this does not look to be specific for the magento website.

Comment: Thanks you for investigating it! I'll open a ticket later there.

Comment: Answered here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296889/359101

Comment: This explanation sounds good .... but ... then there must be an error in your script  .... ?!? I don't care about the -2 rep, but it would be interessting, whats wrong here :)

Comment: Could be. You can try checking manually or modifying the script.

Comment: If i sum up the days totals i come up with 1660 + 1 ... Maybe i'll do it manually again later for every entry  :P Thanks again for your time.